# COUNT() columns by a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I want to make a query on a SQL Compact 4.0 DB-Table, with 2 COUNT()-columns. The first column shall count all rows ( COUNT(*) ) and the second one shall only count the row, when the decimal-value of a specific column is higher as or equal to 3.0

I got this far:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.number) AS Participant, COUNT(b.specificColumn) AS Approved
FROM person AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN test AS b 
ON b.number = a.number
```

This way the second COUNT() will obviously only count rows, that actually have a value != NULL

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it using a count.  Try using a case statement.  Not tested:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.number) AS Participant, 
SUM(case when b.specificColumn >3 then 1 else 0 end) as Approved
FROM person AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN test AS b 
ON b.number = a.number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(a.number) AS Participant,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.specificColumn IS NULL THEN 0
                WHEN b.specificColumn >= 3 THEN 1
                ELSE 0) AS Approved
FROM person AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN test AS b 
ON b.number = a.number
```

Comment: I don't know why exactly, but it gives me an errormessage at the position of the closing parenthesis of the SUM expression.

Comment: I did not test it. Must be due to "WHEN b.specificColumn IS NULL THEN 0" which the working solution did not use.